# Override default snippets in Atom

Tags: code-snippets, atom-editor

I am trying to override default snippets in Atom, because I want to change the default script snippet from

```
<script charset="utf-8"></script>
```

to

```
<script src=""></script>
```

I have put the following into snippets.cson.

```
'.text.html':
  'Comment':
    'prefix': 'com'
    'body': '<!-- $1-->'
  'Script':
    'prefix': 'script'
    'body': '<script src="$1"></script>'
```

My 'com' snippet works fine. But script results in the default snippet, not my new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a snippet that overwrites an existing snippet
2. Quit Atom
3. Start Atom
4. Trigger the newly added snippet, and the original snippet will trigger
5. Open the ~/.atom/snippets.cson file and Save the file (no changes need be made)
6. Trigger the snippet again and it will use the customized version

Apparently its a bug right now.

via https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2695

Comment: Just quitting and starting again worked for me on Atom 1.2.4

Comment: Hey, sorry but I don't use Atom anymore so I have no idea if this works on newer versions. It seems like since this was a bug they would have fixed it eventually though.

Comment: is there a file which holds all the atom core snippets so i can see how it's done by default?

Answer (score 0):

**As of 1.19.5 I can override atoms default snippets by using the traditional procedure for creating snippets, which is written in coffeescript. For example, overwriting my require method looks something like  . . .**

```
    '.source.[*yourlanguage*]':

    'Require':
    'prefix': 'r'
    'body': "require '$1' "
```

**More descriptively**

- Navigate to "snippets" via the file dropdown menu.
- Follow the instructions listed, or continue with me.
- Copy and paste the code I've provided above, below. Replace the *yourlanguage* with the language you are writing the code for you.
- Open a new file, type the character following the 'prefix':, press tab.
- This should give you enough information to contextually figure out how to both overwrite, and write original snippets.